# How to trigger node-sass to compile with a watch file like the way grunt and ruby sass does?

Tags: css, sass, node-sass

As the title stated, I want to node-sass to watch/compile scss files to css without running the command over and over again.

Edit: Is there a grunt task that can run node-sass instead of ruby sass? Because what I've seen is grunt-contrib-sass/compass all use ruby.

Comment: use https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-sass

Comment: this is running without ruby?

Comment: `Compile SCSS to CSS using node-sass`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no native watch task available with node-sass, but you can use [grunt-contrib-watch](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch) and [grunt-sass](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-sass) together to achieve the desired effect.

Comment: however grunt-contrib-watch and grunt-sass support ruby sass instead of node-sass correct?

Comment: grunt-contrib-watch is a generic task for just about anything, it will watch for all sorts of changes regardless of what type of compiler or whether a compiler is even being used. Grunt-contrib-sass is for ruby, while grunt-sass is for node.

Answer (score 5):

Just use the watch flag:

`node-sass src/styles.scss dist/styles.css -w src`